# Alignment issue in subscribed tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

There is some alignment issue in the tags display in Firefox browser.
I have subscribed for [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tags.
When hover those tags the `unsubscribe | rss` text are not properly aligned.

Its happens for many other tags also.

Firefox Version: `45.0.1`
OS: Windows 8.1 Pro

Screenshot for reference:

[image: SQL and SQL-Server Tags alignment issue]

Comment: What browser/OS are you using, and what zoom level? (Looks fine on Chromium 49/Linux)

Comment: @Mat: Yes. In chrome its fine. The issue in Firefox. I updated in the post also.

Comment: Same Issue for **Android**, **Ruby-on-Rails** Tags -- `Windows 7 Firefox 45.0.1`

Comment: Looks like an issue because the "**24.1k followers, 160.8k questions**" line is longer than normal.

Comment: Working on this. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, thanks for reporting it. Fix is already live on production.

Comment: Verified, it is fixed in `rev 2016.4.22.3500`